# Warning regarding not using bundler when running guard init

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard

In my Rails app am getting this warning when running `guard init rspec`:

```
Warning: you have a Gemfile, but you're not using bundler or
RUBYGEMS_GEMDEPS
14:54:15 - INFO - Writing new Guardfile to
/home/ubuntu/railsprojects/sillyfish/Guardfile 14:54:16 - INFO - rspec
guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
```

I don't understand why it's showing. Is it okay to ignore this warning?

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.3.3'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '2.5.0'
end

#custom gems
gem 'puma'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.2'
```

Comment: Did you run the `bundle install` command?

Comment: Yes i did. Eventhough its showing this warning everything seems working fine.

Comment: `guard init rspec` will add guard definition to your Guardfile, but Guardfile is generated by [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard#readme), I think you should add guard gem to your gemfile.

Comment: Tried that but showing same warning.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you run `guard init rspec`, it will use the globally installed `guard-rails`. To run the one installed through your Gemfile, use `bundle exec guard init rspec`. This is also what is recommended in [the documentation](https://github.com/guard/guard#installation).

From the README:

> It's important that you always run Guard through Bundler to avoid errors.

So it's probably best to take this warning seriously, to avoid issues down the line.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. As i already created the guardfile using guard init rspec can i simply delete the guard file and regenerate using bundle exec...?

Comment: That should be fine @ABHILASHV.R. One instance when this can cause issues is when the version of your global Gem and the one specified for the project are different, so it's a good practice to always run commands with the `bundle exec` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

A more technical answer:

There are 3 ways gems can be selected for your Ruby (or Rails) projects:

1. As they are installed on your system (by looking at environment variables such as `$GEM_HOME`), e.g. `guard init rspec` will look for `guard` and `guard-rspec` in your `$GEM_HOME`. Usually RubyGems will use the latest installed versions you have installed (not always what you'll want).
2. If you have Bundler, `bundle exec guard init rspec` will cause your gems to be loaded in versions listed in your `Gemfile.lock`. This also allows you to load gems directly from other folders (anywhere using `:path` option in your `Gemfile`) bundled with the app (e.g. `.bundle` directory) or even downloaded and updated from GitHub (using `:github`, `:branch`, etc. options).
3. If you have a recent version of RubyGems, it can also load your gems from a `Gemfile.lock`. But only if you have the `$RUBYGEMS_GEMDEPS` environment properly set up. It works like Bundler (it reads your `Gemfile.lock`), except it doesn't have all the features (like loading gems from a GitHub repository).

In general, if your project has a `Gemfile`, it's best to use Bundler, because it makes sure all the versions of all gems are matched up to what you expect.